# How to use server side rendering in order to add og meta-tags in react?

Tags: reactjs, express, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, server-side-rendering

What I need is to change the content of og:title in a dynamic way into index.blade.php by using express server. As you know, the only way to change the content of the tags is by using server side rendering because facebook cannot read og tags if they added by react helmet component. So, here what I did:

Into index.balde.php I added these lines:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="$OG_TITLE">
<meta property="og:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION">
```

Then I created server.js file in order to change the content of the tags dynamically through the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs')

app.get('/profile', function(request, response) {
  console.log("Entered the logic");
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../views', 'index.blade.php');

  // read in the index.html file
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    let result = null;
    // replace the special strings with server generated strings
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, 'PROFILE TITLE');
    result = data.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, "PROFILE DESCRIPTIONS");
    //result = data.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, 'https://i.imgur.com/V7irMl8.png');
    response.send(result);
  });
});
app.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + 5000);
});
```

As a result, when I open www.testurl.com:5000/profile The content of the tags have been changed successfully, but my problem is how to make the content of the tags changed without need to add the port number in url, since the requested link should be without the port number. The user does not need to add port number into the URL. 
Is there anyway in react/express to let the server know that when user call www.testurl.com/profile all event listener in the server on port 500 should be called (on other way when access the url without port number app.get('/profile',...) should be called)? Or there is a way to call the url with port number into the basic component to make the event each time user open any page inside the app?

I am really need a help, since i spent a lot of time in order to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hi you could use the `helmet` package in your React app, here's a link to the SSR docs: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#server-usage

Comment: How can I use server usage into my code? I am already using helmet to add the main meta-tags, but now need to add og tags? what I should exactly do?

Comment: Can't you add them the way (assuming) you did it with `title`, `description`?

Comment: No, because when I added them like title and desc. facebook did not detect them! so we need the server side rendering. In my case just need to know how to make the logic into app.get(... works without add port number in the link!